# Cost of token transfer in gas

Tags: erc-20

I am not sure whether I interpret the information from https://ethgasstation.info/index.php page properly.

"Std Cost for Transfer $0.02"

Does it mean that cost of any ERC20 token from one wallet to any other costs $0.02?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the cost for a pure ether transfer (21.000 gas). ERC20 transfers will cost more depending on the implementation. My guess is that it will cost around x4 since you need at least two storage writes, one storage read, and few other operations.

**EDIT** just checked this with "https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/eip20/EIP20.sol. The gas costs for the `transfer`-function are around 80k gas. So my x4 estimation was correct.

Comment: This cost is for a write to a receiving address that has zero balance. If the account already has tokens, it will be around half that.

Comment: @GViz true. In best case it will be 2x15k less, since rewriting a storage slot is only 5k in contrast to 20k for writing to a new slot.