# How does USDC manage to only cost 25k gas instead of 35k++ for transfer?

Tags: solidity, gas, optimization

I am baffled why Centre's USDC only costs around 25k for token transfer instead of 35k++ like other common ERC20.

For example this is Gemini USD:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5006eb71ec62354bf21195bcd88f6ba7401f58e0d0457400abf679de73ba4f23
costs at around 35k

and this is a very simple ERC-20 implementation based on OpenZeppelin library token on rinkeby
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x6ff6547444bc81de31eb3ed3c2cc88b3f341f467ef6d610a1de3999488d00cb5
costs at around 36k

while USDC managed at around 25k
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4d79588d9a7ebbfdf956c0f2ccdd6d30c533c9a8cf568fe7196907ba76811196
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4ec2a4760bdf1d49b8256cec5f23378364c21ed8a853858eaafae82d67ff9dd4
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x431873cfb8ad25fbe0d85732f8db47196cf687a307bf4f3262cc876c9c0a998a

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on how the `transfer` function is implemented and what it does.

I ran some tests with a bare-bones ERC20 contract. Or, actually it doesn't anymore implement all needed functions but it implements the relevant functionality.

With the code given at the bottom of this post, Remix gives me a transaction cost for transfer at **51310 gas**. Let's try to reduce this:

1) Send a second transfer to the same address. **36310 gas**. This is cheaper as writing to an existing slot is cheaper (comments at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/43902/31933)

2) Remove event emission from `transfer` function and send second transfer to the same address: **34482 gas**

3) Replace the *SafeMath* stuff with simpler +/- computations, **33805 gas**

4) Remove all functionality from the function (except `return true`): **23160 gas**

As far as I can tell, the second step is about as reduced as we can get without compromising security.

### Trickery

The previous examples include only tricks that can be done code-wise. If there is a token contract which has a secure and working *transfer* function, I'm guessing it works something like this:

1) The `transfer` function includes only event emission and boolean return, no other functionality. Or strictly speaking even event emission could be removed.

2) A backend system monitors those events (or transactions)

3) The backend system stores the data in a regular database or so

4) Every X minutes the backend system issues a transaction to the token contract to update all the balances. So, basically the cost of token transfers is delegated to the backend system AND the token transfers are bundled together to save in transaction costs.

Used example code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract ERC20Basic {
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    uint256 totalSupply_;
    using SafeMath for uint256;

   constructor(uint256 total) public {  
    totalSupply_ = total;
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }  

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}

library SafeMath { 
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      assert(b <= a);
      return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = a + b;
      assert(c >= a);
      return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's another important case when the sender transfer its full balance. The slot balance will be zero and you will get 15k gas refund.

Comment: @Ismael I checked the txs where USDC having 24k gas, I think it is indeed the case u mentioned, because other txs where it is not the full balance is transferred, the gas used is at around 39k.